# Efficient cholesky decomposition of ABA^T given cholesky(B)

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, linear-regression

Given n*n matrices A, B, and B^1/2 (i.e. cholesky(B) ), where B is positive definite, what are efficient approaches to obtain cholesky(ABA^T)  - is it possible to avoid another full Cholesky decomposition?